# Is there a hardcoded maximum height for Chrome browseraction popups?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I can't make my Chrome extension's browseraction popup taller than 600px. (I am controlling it through document.body.style.height). Is this the hardcoded maximum? I am testing with Chrome v12.0.742.122 on OS X Lion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is. Width is also limited at 800px. It is not stated anywhere in docs though.

Comment: Very useful as I was not aware of this. I'll have to test how the popup in my extension displays when it attempts to exceed this height (as it contains a potentially unlimited list). +1