# dynamically set height of browser action popup based on window size

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When a user clicks my browser action I'd like it's corresponding popup window to (almost) fill the screen.  I need the:

- height/width of the current window

*WHEN*

- the user clicks my popup

I know I can get the height/width of the current window with `chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(currentWindow) { console.log(currentWindow.height); });`, however I don't know how to tell that my popup was opened (event), or how to dynamically set it's size (setting document.body.width or window.inner/outerWidth in the popup's inspector doesn't seem to do it).  Thanks!

Edit: found http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked , however it says it will not fire it a browser action has a popup, is binding to onload in the popup page what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`window.resizeTo` resizes the browser window.

You can pass this information between your parent window and the child popup in any of many creative ways. The simplest I can think of that's pretty much assured to work would be to tack on the dimensions in a query string or hash for the child window URL and then to parse it with JS.

The usual disclaimer applies that there is almost always a better "way" to do things than resizing the browser window.

Comment: hmm, to resize the popup window? (`browser_action.popup` in manifest.json)

Comment: fixed it.  I was looking for something like this:

    window.onload = function() {
        var htmlStyle = document.querySelector('html').style;

        chrome.windows.getCurrent(function(currentWindow) {
            htmlStyle.height = (currentWindow.height*.9) + 'px';
            htmlStyle.width = (currentWindow.width*.9) + 'px';
            console.log(htmlStyle.height, htmlStyle.width);
        });
    };

And [I guess][1] there is a max width/height (800/600px), so the above just gave me that with scrollbars


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904755